# My bukkit plugin won't load

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

I'm relatively new to making bukkit plugins, and i have a basic understanding of java. My plugin won't work. From what i see on other forums, this is a common error but none of the solutions have worked.

Here is my error:

```
[16:18:19 ERROR]: Could not load 'plugins/MtgCraft.jar' in folder 'plugins'
org.bukkit.plugin.InvalidPluginException: Cannot find main class `me.sporech.MagictgCraft'
```

My plugin.yml:

```
name: MtgCraft
main: me.sporech.MagictgCraft
version: 1.8
author: Sporech
description: A basic plugin
```

My code is:

```
package me.sporech;

import java.util.Set;

import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerInteractEvent;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class MagictgCraft extends JavaPlugin {
    public static MagictgCraft plugin;

    @Override
    public void onEnable(){
        getLogger().info("this is the plugin doing it");
    }
    @Override
    public void onDisable(){

    }

    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("hello") && sender instanceof Player) {
            Player player = (Player) sender;
            player.sendMessage("Hello, " + player.getName() + "!");
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerInteractBlock(PlayerInteractEvent event) {
        Player player = event.getPlayer();
        if (player.getItemInHand().getType() == Material.STICK) {
            player.getWorld().strikeLightning(player.getTargetBlock((Set<Material>) null, 200).getLocation());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably ought to tag this with [bukkit] as well.

Comment: Can you search the `latest.log` file in the `logs` folder for this error? The logs should have more information.

Comment: @JarrodRobertson This question is not a duplicate of the question posted. In the question you claim is a duplicate, there were two errors that when resolved led to the resolution of the question: the `onCommand()` method they used took incorrect parameters and the `plugin.yml`'s `description` key was capitalized. _Neither_ of those things are true in this question; therefore, it is no duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

The error is with your `plugin.yml`, not your code. Ensure that the plugin.yml is included in the default package and is inside your jar after exporting/zipping it.

It says that your description is invalid ("`InvalidDescriptionException`"); it may be too short, but that is just a guess. If lengthening your description does not work, try following the description with a "`>`" and a line break, then writing the description on the next line preceded by at least 8 spaces as shown in the example below from one of my plugins:

```
description: >
             This super simple plugin has so many features your head may just implode.
```

The above works in my plugins, though honestly it should not be necessary. Still, it's worth a try.

EDIT:

For future readers who don't want to sift through comments, the problem here was that the `plugin.yml` was not included in the "src" folder or in the default package of the exported jar. Always make sure your `plugin.yml` is in your exported jar in the default package!

Comment: I'll give it a try. Anything that works is good for me. I wouldn't have thought that the length of the description would have a major effect, but it's worth a shot. My plugin.yml is in the project folder; not in the src source folder.

Comment: I tried changing the description to your suggestion; it didn't work. For some reason, when i loaded my server (before changing description), it came up with a different error. I edited my question to use that error instead.

Comment: My plugin.yml was in the wrong place! The tutorial i followed must be outdated or something. I apologise for my previous comment where i said that that it should be in the project folder. On other forums, people always say it shouldn't be in the package, and i took that as it shouldn't be in the src folder at all. Okay, my plugin shows when i do /pl and my onEnable() is working. It isn't doing anything else though. It should reply when a player does '/hello' and make sticks strike lightning >:D. Anyone help?

Comment: @Sporech Ah, yes. The plugin.yml should be in the default package with your jar. The sticks with lightning is not working because you used the `EventHandler` correctly on the method, but you did not register that class as a `Listener`. Add "`implements Listener`" to the class header and to your `onEnable()`, add `getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);`. That will tell Bukkit that your main class (`MagictgCraft`) has event-handling stuff so that your `@EventHandler`-tagged methods will be used.